# Command is not executed on startup

Tags: 12.04, server, startup

I want to start a unicorn server on startup of an Ubuntu server. I changed the file `/etc/rc.local` to have this :

```
echo 'test' >> sudo /tmp/unicorn
test -e /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key || dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
RAILS_ENV=staging
/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs start >> sudo /tmp/unicorn
exit 0
```

When I run the file it works, my server boot but there is nothing in `/tmp/unicorn`. When I reboot the server, unicorn is not running but the symoblic link is created. I don't know how to have a trace.

What can I do?

## Edit after the anwser of Florian Diesch

I made some changes. This is the new script :

```
test -e /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key || dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
export RAILS_ENV=staging
sudo -H -u deployer bash -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs start' >> /tmp/unicorn
exit 0
```

I want to run the script as "deployer" because I use rbenv :

```
echo "starting" >> /tmp/unicorn_log
sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
run "$CMD" >> /tmp/unicorn_log
echo "end starting" >> /tmp/unicorn_log
```

In the file `/tmp/unicorn_log/` it show only "starting". Is it possible to have more logs?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
echo 'test' >> sudo /tmp/unicorn
```

is the same as

```
echo 'test' /tmp/unicorn >> sudo
```

so it appends the line

```
test /tmp/unicorn
```

to the file `sudo` in the current folder.

If you want to append `test` to the file `/tmp/unicorn` using root privileges you should use

```
echo 'test' | sudo tee -a /tmp/unicorn
```

instead. As `/etc/rc.local` is run by root anyway you don't need `sudo` at all but just

```
echo 'test' >> /tmp/unicorn
```

---

Likewise the command

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs start >> sudo /tmp/unicorn
```

is the same as

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs start /tmp/unicorn >> sudo
```

Depending on how `/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs` is written this may or may not produce an error (most likely it doesn't and `/tmp/unicorn` is just ignored).

---

The line

```
RAILS_ENV=staging
```

is just setting the variable `RAILS_ENV` but not exporting it. So it is not available for `/etc/init.d/unicorn_lescollectionneurs` and its child processes. Use

```
export RAILS_ENV=staging
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful anwser. I edited my question.